# INSERT INTO SELECT WITH DECLARING OTHER COLUMS VALUE

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to ask. what is the problem in here I just want to add some value to the the columns and get other value to the other table. I hope you can help me. I only have the problem in the first 4 value.

```
Error: INSERT INTO `orders` (`address`, `payment_method`, `contactnumber`, `order_status`, `cart_id`, `user_id`, `item_id`) VALUES ('Bulacan', '','0912312332', 'Pending' ,(SELECT `cart_id`,`user_id`,`item_id` FROM `cart`))
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

---

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`address`, `payment_method`, `contactnumber`, `order_status``cart_id`, `user_id`, `item_id`)  
                VALUES ('$address', '$payment', '$cnumber', '$status'(SELECT `cart_id`,`user_id`,`item_id` FROM `cart`) )";
```

-Thankyou.

Comment: That does not look good - the given query is widely open for SQL injection. Also, what have you tried to resolve the error?

Comment: You must use `INSERT .. SELECT`, not `INSERT .. VALUES ( .. (SELECT ..))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`address`, `payment_method`, `contactnumber`, 
                      `order_status`, `cart_id`, `user_id`, `item_id`) 
SELECT 'Bulacan', '','0912312332', 'Pending', `cart_id`,`user_id`,`item_id` 
FROM `cart`
WHERE { ??? }
```